# Is there any function available in Load Runner to get run time settings in a variable(s)

Tags: loadrunner

I'm trying to create a loop in my load runner script which will be keep on running till the pacing time equals to zero. Below is the hard coded script.

Here I need to hard code pacing time which was defined in Run time settings. Do we have any function to get the defined pacing time in run time settings to a variable.

```
 int pacingtime = 600;
 starttime = time();
 <Web Requests>
 endtime = time();
 diff = endtime - starttime;
 waittime = pacingtime - diff;
label1:
s1 = time();
<Web Custom Requests>
s2 = time();
s3 = s2 - s1
count = waittime - s3;
waittime = waittime - s3;
 if (count < 0)
     goto label1;
 else
     goto label2;

label2:
return 0;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code and it's implications for your question.  In your run time settings, set number of iterations to 100 with no pacing.  In your additional attributes, add a value for "pacing" with a value of 2.    Execute and watch the logs.

```
long pacing;

vuser_init()
{
    pacing=lr_get_attrib_long("pacing");

    lr_message("pacing: %d",pacing);

    if (pacing==0){ 
        lr_message("Illegal value"); 
    }

    return 0;
}

Action()
{   double how_long;
    merc_timer_handle_t timer=lr_start_timer();

    sleep(rand()%(pacing*1000)+1000);

    how_long=lr_end_timer(timer);

    if ( how_long >= pacing )
    {
        lr_message("delayed %lf seconds, longer than %d seconds\r\nEnding Iterations",
        how_long,
        pacing);

        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        lr_message("delayed %lf seconds, less than %d seconds\r\nSleeping %lf seconds",
        how_long,
        pacing,
        ((double)pacing-how_long));     
    }

    return 0;
}

vuser_end()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you find something in this response that was useful to solving your question?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add this comment. This code was helpful for my requirement.